# Options for ``footmisc'' package

Tags: package-options

Is there a command  for `footmisc` similar to `siunitx`'s `\sisetup` for setting options in another way than via `\usepackage[<options>]{footmisc}`?

I can't find anything in the [manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf).

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: @egreg Okay. Thank you for the comment. If you make it into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't any other way for selecting options other than passing them at loading time.

The package redefines several commands and it wouldn't make sense to change the setup mid document. Perhaps there could be an interface for `symbol` or `symbol*`, but playing with the options that change the formatting or placement of footnotes mid document would most certainly make LaTeX crash disgracefully.