# Pass package options at loading time or later?

Tags: package-options

(This isn't really about a LaTeX issue but more about personal taste and arguments herefore.)

Do you prefer to pass package options at loading time with, say,

```
\usepackage[something]{geoemtry}
\usepackage[something]{siunitx}
```

or later in the preamble with

```
\geometry{something}
\sisetup{something}
```

? I'm asking because I can't make a decision about what to do.

An argument for doing it at loading time is than not all packages have other ways of selecting package options than at loading time (see, e.g., [Options for ``footmisc'' package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147386/options-for-footmisc-package)) and then the first choice makes the preamble more consistent.

Comment: If it makes sense to load options or change them later in the document, a `\...setup` macro is welcome. Otherwise it's better (and more practical) to have the options in the package call.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Can you give an example of when it will make sense to load package options later in the preamble? I can't think of any.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Sometimes packages are loaded with options by the documentclass or a package, which might lead to an option clash. Setting options with `\...setup` *can* prevent this.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg The main examples are `caption` and `siunitx`; also `quoting` has a mixed set of options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This mostly depends on what the options do. Let's look at some cases.

#### Package `babel`

The options are basically the languages used. The main language is the last specified option (or the one given with `main=<language>` from `babel` 3.9). While the language list could in principle be specified later in the preamble, there no point in being able to say `\babelsetup{<languages>}`, because this must necessarily go in the preamble, since they act “globally” on the document.

#### Package `geometry`

One can use `\usepackage[<options>]{geometry}` and zero or more `\geometry{<options>}` commands. This is useful because one can add options when they become necessary; if an option is specified more than once, the last specification wins. However, I don't recommend using more than one `\geometry` command, because this makes the preamble difficult to manage. The most recent versions of `geometry` have a `\newgeometry` command that's similar to `\geometry`, which is not really necessary.

#### Package `footmisc`

The options redefine internal commands. The redefinitions are based on the specified options and are performed when the package code is processed. It would be almost impossible to have a `\footmiscsetup` command.

#### Package `hyperref`

One can specify package options or give one or more `\hypersetup` commands. This works because the relative code is executed at begin document; some of them can also be changed mid document.

#### Package `caption`

*All* options can be changed mid document, so a `\captionsetup` command is welcome in order to locally customize the captions. One can give "global” options as package options and then use `\captionsetup` at the relevant spots.

#### Package `siunitx`

The same considerations as for `caption` hold.

#### Package `imakeidx`

One can specify global options (say `texindy` for using Xindy as the sorting engine), but one can override the global options for a specific index, by giving options to `\makeindex`. An `\imakeidxsetup` command might make sense, to give options that are implicitly used by the subsequently defined indices. But cases where more than three or four indices are rare and defining a complex infrastructure for a few use cases would only make the code more difficult to maintain.

#### Final words

If options to a package are inherently global, there's no point in providing a `\...setup` command. Options that process different package code can only be given as package options, or code maintenance becomes really difficult and conflict prone, because the only way to manage the `\...setup` code is to overload `\AtBeginDocument`, which only slows starting up document processing.

If options can be set locally in the document, a `\...setup` command is what's needed.

Comment: Thanks for the list and the great, simple explanation on why this seems like a missing feature but is really a necessity of the design in the software.